# In Xcode, when I include <iostream>, it seems that stdlib.h is also include. Why?

Tags: c++, xcode, include

I have question about the include of **iostream** when I use Xcode.

After the include of **iostream**, it seems that **stdlib.h** is also included automatically because when I write "**merg**",the **Code Completion** of Xcode gives me the function "**mergesort**" which is a function in the **stdlib.h** according to the **documentation of Xcode**. But I haven't included stdlib.h **explicitely**. So I guess it is the include of iostream that caused the include of stdlib.h. Any one could tell me why?

According to the **C standard**, stdlib.h doesn't have any function like mergesort, why in Xcode, the stdlib.h has such a function？ Does it mean that the stdlib.h in Xcode is not a standard one?

How can I get a **map** of the **dependency of every header file**, for exemple, for a header file example.h, how can I know which other .h files are included in this exemple.h, and which other .h files include in themselves the file exemple.h.

Sorry for this long question, thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: it's implementation-defined.

Which means it depends on the particular standard library implementation. The standard explicitly allows standard library headers to include other standard library headers (or at least define the symbols in them); C++11 17.6.5.2/1:

> A C++ header may include other C++ headers. A C++ header shall provide the declarations and definitions
>   that appear in its synopsis. A C++ header shown in its synopsis as including other C++ headers shall provide
>   the declarations and definitions that appear in the synopses of those other headers.

To keep your code portable (even if only between versions of the same compiler/standard library), you should follow these rules:

1. Don't rely on transitive includes. Always explicitly include all the headers you need.
2. Don't be surprised by transitive includes. They're legal.

Answer (score 0):

> Any one could tell me why?

Presumably, something in your implementation of `iostream` needs something from `stdlib.h`. Standard headers are allowed to include other standard headers if they need them; and, since many headers contain inline function definitions, they will need the headers for anything used by those functions.

> why in Xcode, the `stdlib.h` has such a function？

It's a [BSD extension](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/mergesort/) to the standard library.

> Does it mean that the `stdlib.h` in Xcode is not a standard one?

It does indeed.

> How can I get a map of the dependency of every header file, for exemple, for a header file example.h, how can I know which other .h files are included in this exemple.h, and which other .h files include in themselves the file exemple.h.

Most compilers can output the dependencies of a translation unit. For example, GCC has a `-M` option to do that.